# Recommend textbooks that expain branch cut, Riemann surface and contour integration with branch cut in detail

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, online-resources, branch-cuts, book-recommendation

I read several textbook on complex analysis, but few of them explain the branch cut and Riemann surface in detail and treat the contour integration with branch cut. But this is very important for many application and I'm curious why textbooks on complex analysis all skip this part. So is there some books or materials that can take branch cut seriously? Thanks!

Comment: Not a book but just an example of many

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/381691/not-getting-frac-pi4-for-my-integral-help-with-algebra

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Section ***4.3.2 Integrals with Branch Points*** starting on page 245 from [this](http://www.latp.univ-mrs.fr/~chaabi/ARTICLES%20IMPORTANTS/Autres%20articles%20interessant/Livres/Complex%20Variables%20FOKAS.pdf) pdf book, *Complex Variables* by Ablowitz and Fokas, may suit your needs. You should probably read sections 2.2 and 2.3 first, since they explain branch points and cuts.